# Use a variable value only for x times

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I am making a bash script where I need to run a command using a specific ID. But a single ID can be used only 10 times. After that the ID should change

For Example I have three IDs

```
ID=(abcd1
abcd2
abcd3)

echo $ID
```

Now when this script is executed 10 times then the value of ID should change to abcd2.. more after 10 times then abcd3

I searched on google but couldn't get anything like this

EDIT : I just thought of even getting the idea for using json in such case so I have created one more post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/732551/use-value-of-json-as-a-variable-for-x-number-of-times)

Comment: I don't believe bash has a built-in to know how many times or when a variable is used. But you can create a function which *"returns"* the variable and every time you call that function a counter should be increased (the counter would be inside the function)

Comment: What happens if the script is executed 31 times? Start again with `abcd1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can put counters in the script.  Then have the script update them each time it's run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

_list=(
  abc
  def
  ghi
)
_list_index=0 # autoupdate
_list_usage_counter=0 # autoupdate

max_uses=10
if [ $((_list_usage_counter)) -eq $((max_uses - 1)) ] ; then
  # reset counter
  sed -Ei \
    -e "s/^(_list_usage_counter)\=${_list_usage_counter}( # autoupdate)\$/\1=0\2/" \
    "$(readlink -f "$0")"
  _list_usage_counter=0

  # update list index
  sed -Ei \
    -e "s/^(_list_index)\=${_list_index}( # autoupdate)\$/\1=$((++_list_index))\2/" \
    "$(readlink -f "$0")"
fi

# make sure index is not out of bounds
if [ $_list_index -ge ${#_list[@]} ] ; then
  echo "no more items to use"
  exit
fi

# ... do stuff ...
echo "item: ${_list[_list_index]}"
echo "used: $((_list_usage_counter + 1))"

# update counter
sed -Ei \
  -e "s/^(_list_usage_counter)\=${_list_usage_counter}( # autoupdate)\$/\1=$((++_list_usage_counter))\2/" \
  "$(readlink -f "$0")"
```

Comment: what if using a json file & updating the counters over there ?

Comment: I've updated the script.  Anything more than this, you'll need to figure out on your own.

Comment: You didn't mention json in your question.  If using an external data source, use whatever program you normally use to read and update data.

Comment: You can try [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to process json.   I haven't used it before, so can't help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your "counters" to the temp files:

```
#!/bin/bash

ID=(abcd1 abcd2 abcd3)

#if script run for the first time create "file" counters
id_file="/tmp/$(basename ${0})_id"
us_file="/tmp/$(basename ${0})_usage"
if [[ ! -f $id_file ]]; then
   echo "0" > $id_file
fi

if [[ ! -f $us_file ]]; then
   echo "0" > $us_file
fi

#set variables
max_usage=10
id="$(cat $id_file)"
usage="$(cat $us_file)"

#if all ids used, exit script
if [[ $id -eq ${#ID[@]} ]]; then
   echo "No more ids available! Create new ones and delete '$id_file' and '$us_file' files."
   exit
fi

if [[ $usage -lt $max_usage ]]; then
   usage="$(( $(cat $us_file) + 1 ))"
   echo $usage > $us_file
   # do your stuff
   echo "Your id is: ${ID[$id]}."
else
   #reset usage and change (use next) id
   usage="1"
   echo "1" > $us_file
   id=$((id+1))
   echo "$id" > $id_file
   if [[ $id -lt ${#ID[@]} ]]; then
      echo "Your id x is: ${ID[$id]}."
   else
      echo "No more ids available! Create new ones and delete '$id_file' and '$us_file' files."
   fi
fi
```