# Use Value of Json as a variable for x number of times

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, jq

I have a json file with the ids of list for their entries

```
[
    {
        "list_id": 1,
        "list_key": "gnfijgndngd458wjfisdnfpon",
        "entries": 0
    },
    {
        "list_id": 2,
        "list_key": "gnfijgndndfp[mfphm,]ordjkt9roh,mkn",
        "entries": 0
    },
    {
        "list_id": 3,
        "list_key": "gnfijgnsnfc0wr8envpuh-[sijjnhmgmvisbfusf",
        "entries": 0
    }
]
```

The Maximum entries per is equal to 100. Means I can use one list_id ony 100 times.

How can I use these ids as a variable in a bash script? Like after 100 entries it should change to another list_id

Comment: Apart from the fact that the number is stored in a JSON file, this sounds exactly identical to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/732523/116858).  There's nothing inherent in JSON that makes this question different from the previous one, it's just that you would have to read the number and store an incremented value.  The actual logic is identical to that which is needed  to solve your other query. If you instead want to ask about parsing and updating your JSON, then ask about that.

Comment: Actually I thought that using json will be bit easy. Because the other answer I myself found it difficult to understand

Answer (score 2):

To get the `list_id` of the first element of your top-level anonymous array that has an `entries` value less than 100, you may use

```
jq 'map(select(.entries < 100)) | first.list_id' file
```

(This returns a single integer, the `list_id` value.)

To increment the `entries` value by one,

```
jq 'map(select(.entries < 100)) | first.entries += 1' file
```

or, if you have a specific `list_id` that you would want to increment the `entires` value for, assuming each `list_id` is unique,

```
jq --argjson list_id "$list_id" 'map(select(.list_id == $list_id).entries += 1)' file
```

(These return an updated document.)

So, in your shell script:

```bash
# get list_id
list_id=$( jq 'map(select(.entries < 100)) | first.list_id' file )

# check whether we got the string "null" back, which indicates
# that we found no entry ith "entries" less than 100
if [ "$list_id" = null ]; then
    echo 'No list_id with entries < 100 available' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# increment counter (in-place edit using GNU sponge)
jq --argjson list_id "$list_id" 'map(select(.list_id == $list_id).entries += 1)' file | sponge file
```

After running the above script 110 times, the JSON document in `file` would be the equivalent of the following (assuming allthe `entries` counters started at zero):

```json
[
   { "entries": 100, "list_id": 1, "list_key": "gnfijgndngd458wjfisdnfpon" },
   { "entries": 10, "list_id": 2, "list_key": "gnfijgndndfp[mfphm,]ordjkt9roh,mkn" },
   { "entries": 0, "list_id": 3, "list_key": "gnfijgnsnfc0wr8envpuh-[sijjnhmgmvisbfusf" }
]
```

---

If the `list_id` values are strictly non-zero, then the above shell script can be made shorter by using `jq` with its `-e` (`--exit-status`) option:

```bash
if ! list_id=$( jq -e 'map(select(.entries < 10)) | first.list_id' file )
then
    echo 'No list_id with entries < 100 available' >&2
    exit 1
fi

# increment counter (in-place edit using GNU sponge)
jq --argjson list_id "$list_id" 'map(select(.list_id == $list_id).entries += 1)' file | sponge file
```

Note that none of the above code attempts to do any file locking, and that if two or more concurrent processes run the script, then there is a clear race-condition in the code (since the fetching of `list_id` and the updating of the counter is not a single atomic operation).